# Check for poorly placed meta refresh

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am scraping multiple pages with a loop and need to check a few things on them. One page I have in my chain has a poorly placed `<meta>`:

```html
…
</head>
<body>
…
    <main>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=example.com">
        </head>
    <main>
…
```

Even with `waitUntil: 'networkidle2'` the redirect happens after the `page.goto` promise resolved:

```js
    for (const url of urls) {
        await page
            .goto(url, {
                waitUntil: 'networkidle2',
            })
            .then(callback);
    }
```

So if run any checks with for example `$$eval` the page context gets destroyed. Sure I can go with `waitForSelector` but I want to run my checks on the original url not on the redirected url.

How can I handle this error or maybe how can I prevent this, without using any timeout hacks?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you need to prevent an instant client-side redirection. Not sure if any of these ways will do, but you can try any separately or together:

1. Use `page.setRequestInterception()` to abort redirection.
2. Handle `'domcontentloaded'` event to delete `meta` element.
3. Use `page.evaluateOnNewDocument()` to delete `meta` element.
4. Save `page.content()` value, delete `meta` element in the source and reapply it with `page.setContent()`.

Comment: 1. doesn't work, because the redirect isn't in the redirect chain
2. How? 
3. Doesn't work with `await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(
                    'document.querySelector(\'meta[http-equiv="refresh"]\').remove()'
                );`
4. is also to late, the redirect happens immediately after invoking of further page functions

Comment: 2. Maybe: `await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' } ); await page.evaluate( 'document.querySelector(\'meta[http-equiv="refresh"]\').remove()' ); `